# Calculating Velocity from Arrays in BigQuery

Tags: performance, google-bigquery

I have one table like such

```
CREATE TABLE location (
  reportId STRING NOT NULL,
   
  Neck_Location Array <FLOAT64>,
  
  Trunk_Location Array <FLOAT64>,
  
  L_Shoulder_Location Array <FLOAT64>,
  
  R_Shoulder_Location Array <FLOAT64>, 
  
  L_Elbow_Location Array <FLOAT64>,
  R_Elbow_Location Array <FLOAT64>,
  
  L_Knee_Location Array <FLOAT64>,
  R_Knee_Location Array <FLOAT64>
  FOREIGN KEY (reportId) REFERENCES report(reportId) NOT ENFORCED
);
```

and another table report which looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE report (
  reportId STRING NOT NULL,
  frameRate FLOAT64,
  PRIMARY KEY (reportId) NOT ENFORCED,
);
```

I have been banging my head on how I can calculate the relative velocity on each of these angles in a query. I have tried using LEAD and LAG to grab the previous and next index but to no avail. All arrays have the same length.

The algorithm I am thinking of using would look like this in psudocode

```
Arr's structure would be Arr[Neck_Location] = [49.433333333333088,33.109,49.46666666666642,33.109,49.499999999999751,33.109,49.533333333333083,33.109,49.5666666] for example. It would contain the array for each field.

fields = ["Neck_Location","Trunk_Location","L_Shoulder_Location","R_Shoulder_Location","L_Elbow_Location","R_Elbow_Location","L_Knee_Location","R_Knee_Location"]

velocityArr = []
secondsPerFrame= 1/framerate

For field of fields:
   For i = 1; i <= len(Arr[field]); i++:
       Distancediff = Arr[field][i] - Arr[field][i-1] / secondsPerFrame
       velocityArr[field][i] = distanceDiff

Return velocityArr
```

Sorry for the messy psudo code. I just figured this was the best way to represent the problem. Please let me know if I can help in any other way.

I tried LAG, LEAD, etc. my current approach is the generate another array with each timestep but there has to be a better, more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `unnest` SQL UDF you need two functions. One to calculate the speed and one to sum up the values.

```sql
create temp function speed(A any type,framerate any type) as ((
  With data as (
    select lag(x) over last_element as last_x,* 
    from unnest(A) as x with offset 
    #where x is not null # remove null values
    window last_element as (order by offset)
    )
    Select array_agg( if(offset=0,0, (x-last_x)*framerate) order by offset )  from data
    #where last_x is not null 

));
create temp function sum_array(A any type) as 
((
Select array_agg(Y order by offset) from
(
  Select sum(x) over sum_me as Y , *
  from unnest(A) as x with offset 
  window sum_me as (order by offset rows  between unbounded preceding and current row )
)
));

with tbl as (select [49.433333333333088,33.109,49.46666666666642,33.109,49.499999999999751,33.109,49.533333333333083,33.109,49.5666666] as Neck_Location
)

SELECT *,
speed(Neck_Location,1) as speed,
sum_array(speed(Neck_Location,1)) as speed_sum
 from tbl
```

Or you can use a UDF with JavaScript to start with your pseudo code:

```sql
create temp function speed(Arr array<Float64>, framerate float64)
returns array<Float64>
language js as 
"""
var secondsPerFrame= 1/framerate;
var velocityArr = [0];
var Distancediff = 0;

   for(let i = 1; i < Arr.length; i++) {
       Distancediff = (Arr[i] - Arr[i-1] ) / secondsPerFrame
       velocityArr[i] = Distancediff
   }

return velocityArr;

"""
;

with tbl as (select [49.433333333333088,33.109,49.46666666666642,33.109,49.499999999999751,33.109,49.533333333333083,33.109,49.5666666] as Neck_Location
)

SELECT *,
speed(Neck_Location,1) as speed,

 from tbl
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much for taking time out of your day to respond to my question. I'm going to give this a try and will let you know. Thank you, Samuel.

Comment: Samuel, This worked great! I just changed a couple things like (x-last_x)*framerate to (x-last_x)/(1/framerate). Thank you so much for your help.